# Writing to /proc File System from Android Activity in java

Tags: java, android, c, linux, linux-kernel

I have download Android source code and flashed it to device. I have written LKM which reads/writes information to /proc/myFile. I want to write to /proc/myFiLE file from my android activity but using java code not native. I know in native code we can can use `system( )` system call to write using echo command but i do not know that how to write from java code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's stopping you from creating a File object and a FileOutputStream and using them? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this.

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command")

Answer (score 2):

Just treat them as normal files. You can use the usual `File` and `*Stream` objects to write what you need.